# Copying value in mysql from column1 to column2

Tags: mysql

I have a table named table1 with column1(pk) and column2.

When inserting into table1 in sql, is it possible to check the value of column2 and **insert the value of column1 into columns2 if the value for column2 is null**?

If so how do I do it?

Comment: I don't get the question here.  If you are making an `INSERT` into the table, there would not be an existing value.  That is unless you are trying to do `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use an `IF` statment:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column2 = IF(column1 IS NOT NULL, column1, 'Something else')
```

Comment: Where is your check that column2  is null?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make a BEFORE INSERT trigger for that.

Syntax: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_insert.php

Documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make any changes to your SQL statement, you could define a **`BEFORE INSERT`** trigger on `table1` that conditionally assigns  a value to column2.  The body of the trigger would contain a pattern like this:

```
  IF NEW.column2 IS NULL THEN
    SET NEW.column2 = NEW.column1;
  END IF;
```

(NOTE: The value of `NEW.column1` is the value supplied in the statement, or NULL if it's omitted. That is, if the value of `column1` is being assigned by `auto_increment`, that assigned value is *not* available in the `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, so it can't be copied to `column2`.)

---

Otherwise, you would need to modify the `INSERT` statement itself, to use an appropriate expression to supply a value for `column2`, e.g.

```
 IFNULL(:col2val,:col1val)
```